# I only pay with dollars

Tags: code-golf, math, string

As the title -- although discretely -- hints, I only pay with dollars.

### The challenge

Write a function/program that takes a string as input, which is a monetary value preceded by a symbol. `ex) £4.99`. Then, return that same amount converted to USD.

### Input

You will get a string as input. It will have the currency symbol followed by a number with two decimal places (which could be `.00`). There will either be decimal points `.` and/or commas `,` separating the number. The following currency symbols will come in the inputs:

> Euro: €
> Pound Sterling: £
> Yuan Renminbi: ¥

Also, there will be a comma or decimal point depending on the currency to separate the 'dollars' from the 'cents':

> Euro: #.###,##
> Pound Sterling: #,###.##
> Yuan Renminbi: #,###.##

### Output

You will convert the input from the currency determined by the symbol to USD, rounding to two decimal places. The output will be in the format `$#,###.##`, and there will of course be more numbers on the left of the output if need be (**EDIT: this means that there is an arbitrary number of commas in the output, just like in the input**). The currency exchange rate we will be using are below.

You can assume that the input contains a symbol that is only one of the above (`€ £ ¥ . ,`)--that it is always valid.

### Exchange rates

```
€1 : $1.10
£1 : $1.37
¥1 : $0.15
```

### Examples

```
Input:
€1,37
£4.00
¥2,782,122.78

Respective output:
$1.51
$5.48
$417,318.42
```

### Final words

1. If you use one of the above symbols (€, £, ¥), you may count them as 1 byte
2. This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: If you want to use true l10n, renminbi should have a comma delimiter at the 10k mark, not at the 1k mark. (e.g., `10,0000.15`)

Comment: It's funny that if you've posted this question yesterday, the English Pound's exchange rate would have been `£1 : $1.51` xD

Comment: Ok @Adnan, I'll do that. Done.

Comment: Hmm, is that output correct? `1.37 * 1.10 = 1,507 = 1,51` (so not `1.52`) and `4.00 * 1.37 = 5.48` (not `5.50`) and `2782122.78 * 0.15 = 417318.417 = 417318.42` (not `420165.06`)... :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, I just realized that, when using Google to convert, the exchange rate had already changed. Fixed it.

Comment: What's the maximum input? (Basically, I tested some answers with a huge input (e.g. ¥892,213,489,287,893,323,479,987.67) and all of them gave a rounding/overflow error (e.g. I got $1,222,332,480,324,410,000,000,000.00)

Comment: @ev3commander, I'd say that the max input is just about the max-int for each respective language. I don't want to say something too specific now because I don't want to invalidate Abu answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

Forgot about conditional application `W`.

```
.F"${:,.2f}"*v-tXWqhQ\€Q",.")\,@[1.1.15d1.37)Ch
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.F%22%24%7B%3A%2C.2f%7D%22%2av-tXWqhQ%5C%E2%82%ACQ%22%2C.%22%29%5C%2C%40%5B1.1.15d1.37%29Ch&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%E2%82%AC1%2C37%22%0A%22%C2%A34.00%22%0A%22%C2%A52%2C782%2C122.78%22&debug=0).

Comment: Hmm.. is it me or is this a pretty big answer for Pyth in terms of bytes? o.Ô It's almost 1/4th of my [Java answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83758/52210)! (Usually it's 1/50th or so.. xD)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yeah, the string formatting and the raw currency data make up almost half the size.

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3.6 (pre-release), 87

```
lambda s:f"${int(s.translate({46:'',44:''})[1:])*[110,15,0,137][ord(s[0])%4]/1e4:,.2f}"
```

Uses [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to evaluate the result and [format it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

`s.translate({46:'',44:''})` removes dots and commas from `s`, thus making it a valid `int` literal, then `int(...)` converts it into the actual `int` object.

Answer (score 4):

### Convex, <s>56</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

```
(\®\.|,"ö)\e_\'.\++~\"€£¥"#[1.1_.27+.15]=*"%,.2f"\Ø'$\
```

Well, this can definitely be shortened. [Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=KFzCrlwufCwiw7YpXGVfXCcuXCsrflwi4oKswqPCpSIjWzEuMV8uMjcrLjE1XT0qIiUsLjJmIlzDmCckXA&input=&args=wqUyLDc4MiwxMjIuNzg)

Saved a byte thanks to Lynn!

Explanation to come when I can get access to a computer.

Comment: How about `[1.1_.27+.15]`?

Comment: @Lynn thats genius! Thanks!

Comment: "Explanation to come when I can get access to a computer," implying that that little nugget of awesome unreadability was written on a _mobile device_. well done, learned scholar. well done.

Comment: @strugee Yeah, Ive been out all day but I have made a CP-1252 keyboard for my iPhone for this purpose.

Comment: Why the last 55 bytes mark is struck out? Also, typo in *definetely* - *definitely*.

Comment: @zyabin101 oops, good catch!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>240</s> <s>227</s> <s>215</s> <s>211</s> <s>207</s> <s>202</s> <s>199</s> 196 bytes

(201 - 2 bytes because of the rule "*If you use one of the above symbols (€, £, ¥), you may count them as 1 byte*")
Thanks to *@Frozn* for saving a lot of bytes.

```
String c(String a){int c=a.charAt(0);return java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale.US).format(new Long(a.substring(1).replaceAll(",|\\.",""))*(c<'¥'?1.37:c>'¥'?1.1:.15)/100);}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/aYoXta)

```
class Main{
  static String c(String a){
    int c = a.charAt(0);
    return java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale.US)
        .format(new Long(a.substring(1).replaceAll(",|\\.","")) *
                 (c < '¥'
                   ? 1.37
                   : c > '¥'
                     ? 1.1
                     : .15
                  ) / 100);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("€1,37"));
    System.out.println(c("£4.00"));
    System.out.println(c("¥2,782,122.78"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
$1.51
$5.48
$417,318.42
```

Comment: `char c=a.charAt(0)` (all in all you don't need `c` at all, see my answer)

Comment: By pulling the `d *` out of the ternary you save some duplication. Looks like this: `d*(c=='€'?1.1:c=='£'?1.37:.15)/100`.

Comment: @Frozn Thanks. Also, unfortunately `/100` and `*.01` is the same amount of bytes, and `c=='€'?.011:c=='£'?.0137:.0015` is also the exact same as with the `/100`.

Comment: Yeah that's bad. But here is the good news: Thanks to the unique unicode values of the currency signs you can shorten it because `'£' < '¥' < '€'`. Thus you can write `c<'¥'?1.37:c>'¥'?1.1:.15` which is 2 characters shorter.

Comment: Just saw we don't need `d` anymore as it is only used once.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107

Simple and straightforward<s>, probably more golfable</s>

Note: tested in FireFox. Many browsers (especially mobile) have buggy support of `toLocaleString`

```js
a=>(a.replace(/\D/g,'')/1e4*(a<'¥'?137:a>'€'?110:15)).toLocaleString('en',{style:'currency',currency:'USD'})
```

**TEST**

```js
function test()
{
  var i=I.value
  var F=a=>(a.replace(/\D/g,'')/1e4*(a<'¥'?137:a>'€'?110:15)).toLocaleString('en',{style:'currency',currency:'USD'})
  O.textContent=F(i)
}

test()
```

```html
<input id=I value='¥2,782,122.78' oninput='test()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: I could only test this on Firefox. Can you give me a link to Firefoex?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Google "Firefoex", it will give you the correct link even if it's misspelled

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.5, <s>137</s> <s>131</s> <s>121</s> <s>120</s> 117 bytes:

*(Thanks to [Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31343/maltysen) for a hint on saving 6 bytes `(137 -> 131)`!)*

```
lambda u:'${:,.2f}'.format(float(u[1:].translate([{44:''},{44:46,46:''}]['€'in u]))*{'€':1.1,'£':1.37,'¥':.15}[u[0]])
```

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/RjjqOt)

Comment: you don't need to do your own rounding, `.format()` does it for  you if you do `${:,.2f}`

Comment: @Maltysen Thanks! I did not know I could do that! :)

Comment: `46:0` replaces dots with NUL characters.

Comment: @vaultah So what? It works for Euro inputs.

Comment: @vaultah Well, it works perfectly fine on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/RjjqOt) and my computer.

Comment: Your code passes all the tests from the OP but it doesn't work properly for `€2.121,37`.

Comment: @vaultah Oh, all right. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, <s>101</s> 98

```
lambda x:'${:,.2f}'.format(int(x[1:].translate({44:'',46:''}))*{'€':110,'£':137,'¥':15}[x[0]]/1e4)
```

The Euro, Pound, and Yen symbols are counted as 1 byte/character each, per the challenge rules.

Instead of translating among or interpreting thousands and decimal separators, these are just stripped out to give a plain digit string.

The digit string (after the currency symbol) is converted to an integer.

The currency symbol is used as an index into a dictionary of conversion rates; the conversion is performed by multiplying by the conversion rate and dividing by 10000.

The result is formatted with a leading dollar sign, two decimal places of precision, and commas for grouping.

Comment: Why don't you delete the 0 from 1.10 to save 1 byte?

Comment: Maybe you can skip the . in the ratios and divide by 1e4

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 198 bytes

```
(s:string)="$"+(System.Double.Parse(if s.[0]='€'then s.[1..].Replace(".","").Replace(',','.')else s.[1..].Replace(",",""))*(if s.[0]='€'then 1.1 else if s.[0]='£'then 1.37 else 0.15)).ToString("N2")
```

Un-Golfed:

```
let IOnlyUseDollars(s : string) = 
    let cur = s.[0]
    let str = if cur = '€' then s.[1..].Replace(".","").Replace(',', '.') else s.[1..].Replace(",","")
    let amt = System.Double.Parse(str)
    let dol = amt * (if cur = '€' then 1.1 else if cur = '£' then 1.37 else 0.15)
    "$" + dol.ToString("N2")
```

I'm still trying to figure out F#, so dealing with the thousands separators is taking up a lot of bytes.

According to the challenge rules, the Euro, Yen, and Pound symbols count as one byte each, despite how Unicode stores them internally.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 112 bytes NOT COMPETING

```
def c(x):x=x.translate(None,",.");print“$”+‘{:,.2f}’.format([1.1,1.37,0.15][“€£¥”.index(x[0])]*int(x[1:])/100,2)
```

This is not competing because I do not think that I am allowed to answer my own question.

Also, I have not yet had a chance to run this on a computer, but it seems to me like it should work. I will run it on a computer as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: You are completely fine to answer your own question. Some people even come up with an answer before making the question itself. Usually they still get beaten by golfing languages like Jelly, Pyth, Pyke and alike, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 117 bytes

```
function f($s){return'$'.number_format(ereg_replace('[^0-9]','',substr($s,1))*[E=>.011,P=>.0137,Y=>.0015][$s[0]],2);}
```

This makes use of a deprecated function; replace `ereg_replace('[^0-9]'` with `preg_replace('%[^\d]%'` to make the code fully modern; adds 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 54 bytes

```
'$q(\",."-de-2\"€£¥"#[1.1 1.37 .15]=*2mOs'./~\3/',*'.@
```

[Try it here!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=JyRxKFwiLC4iLWRlLTJcIuKCrMKjwqUiI1sxLjEgMS4zNyAuMTVdPSoybU9zJy4vflwzLycsKicuQA&input=4oKsMSwzNw)

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site! Just so you know, there is an online CJam interpreter [here](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=JyRxKFwiLC4iLWRlLTJcIuKCrMKjwqUiI1sxLjEgMS4zNyAuMTVdPSoybU9zJy4vflwzLycsKicuQA&input=4oKsMSwzNw) You could link to that in your post to make it easier for reader to run/test your answer.